# DataGridView minimal amount of rows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, rows

I'm pretty much to C# and I'm trying to create a simple network analyzer. I want to be able to see packets in a datagridview. The imagined lay-out can be compared with tools like wireshark. I would like my datagridview to always be "filled". By filled I mean that it always contains rows even if these are empty.

When starting the application for example I would like the grid to be fully filled with rows. The total height of the gridView is a multiple of the row height, so it contains enough rows so it's exactly 100% filled. When adding data however I would like that these empty rows do not count so data overwrites these empty rows, and when removed these rows return if otherwise the DataGridView would not be fully filled. I realize I might explain this a bit poorly but I'm not sure how I could try to bring across what I mean otherwise. The way Excel works would be ideal for example. You start with a full screen with empty cells, and you can add things to them. If you add more data than fits a scoll bar gets introduced to still be able to see all data. When you remove it the scrollbar becomes smaller until eventually it's not needed anymore but the cells remain shown. (even if empty)

Thanks in advance,

Arnold

-edit- 
Regarding height of things: I'd probably want things to be resizable in the future. So that information could probably not be exploited.

Comment: Is there a question here, or do you just want the solution written for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap a DataGridView with a user control to override adding and removing rows.

If you are removing a row - it must be real (not marked as "place holder" [tag?]).
and if your Count is less than IdealCount, add a "place holder" row.

If you are adding a row - if your Count is less than IdealCount, remove the last "place holder" row.

Initialize with IdealCount number of "place holder" rows.

Let the rows be sorted by a hidden column of default value 0 and a value of 1 for "place holders" or simply maintain the rows order yourself in the Add override. This way the "place holders" will always be last (and there won't be any, if Count > IdealCount).